# Adding buttons next to a combobox in a container

Tags: extjs, combobox

I'm trying to place buttons next to a combobox in ExtJS. I've read that I should be using a FieldContainer. But I am not using `xtype`. I'm using ExtJS 4 and this is my code:

```
        var dateTypeSelect = Ext.create('Ext.form.ComboBox', {
            store: dateTypeStore,
            padding: 5, 
            width: 80,
            queryMode: 'local',
            displayField: 'name',
            valueField: 'id',
        });            

        var submitButton = Ext.create('Ext.Button', {
            text: 'Some Button',
        });

        var upperContainer = Ext.create('Ext.container.Container', {
            renderTo: 'some_div',
            autoFit: true,
            layout: 'hbox',
            style: {
                background: 'white',
            },
            items: [dateTypeSelect, submitButton],
        });
```

Only the drop down menu gets displayed.

Comment: There is no problem which is working properly. Try to in sencha fiddle, you will see.

Comment: I'm confused... what does not using an `xtype` have to do with not being able to use a FieldContainer?  All xtypes map to an actual namespace.  [Per the documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.form.FieldContainer), a `fieldcontainer` xtype maps to `Ext.form.FieldContainer`.